# What is the equivalent of jBoss 6 AS "lib" folders in wildfly 8.2.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss6.x, wildfly-8

In jBoss AS 6, there are three `lib` folders.

```
jboss-6.1.0.Final/lib
jboss-6.1.0.Final/common/lib
jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/lib
```

For the last one i.e. `jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/lib`, the equivalent in wildfly 8.2.0 is `wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/lib` for standalone mode.

For the first two `lib` folders, what are the equivalents in wildfly 8.2.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application server's own classes are now stored under modules. If you need your own jars, these should either be packaged inside your deployment, or if shared between many deployments or needed by the container itself (e.g jdbc driver) then these should be added to modules